# How to select and tag range of values that fall in time window in one dataframe based on timestamp in second dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, window, group

I want to select all the values in df1 within 30 seconds of time in the timestamp in df2.

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

For example for time 2:00:53 PM in df2, I want to select all values in df1 between 2:00:23 PM and 2:00:53 PM and tag them with Group II and SubGroup 1.

I am completely new to programming and just know how to import data using Python. Can anyone please suggest the functions I can use with examples?

I have just read about Select and other functions and have not practically implemented any in Python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.